# Problem Outputting 2.5 Khz Signal ATTiny85 with Digispark

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, avr, pwm, frequency

I am relatively new working with the Digispark IDE and I am having some issues with something that should be really simple.

I am trying to output a 2.5 kHz square wave signal, that will oscillate +/- 500 Hz. So it goes from 2000Hz to 3000 Hz from a micro controller that uses a ATTiny85 with Digispark's IDE.

I found this tutorial online: https://digistump.com/wiki/digispark/tricks which explains what I want to do. As they said, to modify the HW PWM frequency I changed the value from 64 to 8  of the MS_TIMER_TICK_EVERY_X_CYCLES inside wiring.c

Because of this I managed to get a higher frequency value. But I was not able to tune it, that is why I continued with the Software PWM manipulation

I have used this code:

```
#include <TinySoftPwm.h>
#include <DigiUSB.h>

#define HW_PWM_PIN               0 /* Used to check HW PWM with analogWrite() */
#define SW_PWM_BUILT_IN_LED_PIN  1 /* Digispark Model A (Rev2) built-in LED pin number (Change it to 2 for Model B) */
#define TIME_TEST_PIN            5 /* Used to check with oscilloscope micros(), millis() are still OK */

void setup()
{
   TinySoftPwm_begin(128, 0); /* 128 x TinySoftPwm_process() calls before overlap (Frequency tuning), 0 = PWM init for all declared pins */
   pinMode(TIME_TEST_PIN, OUTPUT);
   DigiUSB.begin(); 
}

void loop()
{
static uint32_t PwmStartUs=micros();
static uint32_t PwmStartMs=millis();
static uint8_t  Pwm=0;
static int8_t   Dir=1;
static boolean  State=LOW;
static uint32_t BlinkStartMs=millis();

  /***********************************************************/
  /* Call TinySoftPwm_process() with a period of 60 us       */
  /* The PWM frequency = 128 x 60 # 7.7 ms -> F # 130Hz      */
  /* 128 is the first argument passed to TinySoftPwm_begin() */
  /***********************************************************/
  if((micros() - PwmStartUs) >= 60)
  {
    /* We arrive here every 60 microseconds */
    PwmStartUs=micros();
    TinySoftPwm_process(); /* This function shall be called periodically (like here, based on micros(), or in a timer ISR) */
  }

  /*************************************************************/
  /* Increment/decrement PWM on LED Pin with a period of 10 ms */
  /*************************************************************/
  if((millis()-PwmStartMs) >= 10)
  {
    /* We arrived here every 10 milliseconds */
    PwmStartMs=millis();
    Pwm+=Dir; /* increment or decrement PWM depending of sign of Dir */
    TinySoftPwm_analogWrite(SW_PWM_BUILT_IN_LED_PIN, Pwm); /* Software PWM: Update built-in LED for Digispark */
    analogWrite(HW_PWM_PIN, Pwm); /* Copy Pwm duty cycle to Hardware PWM */
    if(Pwm==255) Dir=-1; /* if PWM reaches the maximum: change direction */
    if(Pwm==0)   Dir=+1; /* if PWM reaches the minimum: change direction */
  }

  /* Blink half period = 5 ms */
  if(millis()-BlinkStartMs>=5)
  {
    BlinkStartMs=millis();
    digitalWrite(TIME_TEST_PIN, State);
    State=!State;
  }

  /* Check USB is still working */
  if(DigiUSB.available()) /* Just hit "Enter" in the digiterm to check USB */
  {
    DigiUSB.read(); /* just to clear the Rx buffer */
    DigiUSB.println(F("DigiUSB is still alive!"));
  }
  DigiUSB.refresh();

}
```

It doesn't matter what I do, I am reading an oscillating 4.065 kHz - 4.049 kHz value.

What am I doing wrong?
Is my oscilloscope broken?
Should I be doing this any other way?

Comment: FYI to other EE.SE members: This question is a copy & paste from the Digistump Forums [(link)](http://digistump.com/board/index.php?topic=2332.0), and although it has not *yet* had a reply there, the OP's question might be solved by an answer there at any time, of course.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this on timer 0 in CTC mode. If your MCU is running at 8MHz you need a prescaler setting of 8 to reach the frequency range you are after. Inverting the frequency formula from the datasheet gives you the correct counts for the overflow. We do this separately using our favorite language (mine is Haskell):

```
module Main (main) where

f_cpu = 8e6
freq n c = f_cpu / (2 * n * (1 + c))
count n f = f_cpu / (f * 2 * n) - 1

main :: IO ()
main = mapM_ (print . round . count 8) [ 2e3, 2.5e3, 3e3 ]
```

which gives us 249, 199, 166 respectively. We are now ready to write the program:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

void setup()
{
    TCCR0A = _BV(WGM01) | _BV(COM0A0);  // CTC mode w toggle channel A on compare match
    TCCR0B = _BV(CS01);                 // clock select prescale = 8
    DDRB |= _BV(0);                     // enable channel A = OC0A (PB0) output
}

void loop()
{
    static uint8_t i = 0;

    switch (++i & 0x3)
    {
        case 0: OCR0A = 249; break;     // 2kHz
        case 1: OCR0A = 199; break;     // 2.5kHz
        case 2: OCR0A = 166; break;     // 3kHz
        case 3: OCR0A = 199; break;     // 2.5kHz
    }

    _delay_ms(2000);
}

int main()
{
    setup();
    for (;;)
        loop();
}
```

This will cycle through the frequencies 2, 2.5 and 3kHz in 500Hz steps 2 seconds each. I have tested on a bare ATTiny85 running at 8MHz and measured it on my scope: 2.01kHz, 2.52kHz and 3.01kHz is what I get.

If you can't use timer 0 it should be straightforward to achieve the same on timer 1 (it has more prescaling options and wider range).